# What purpose does ELF's stack-size metadata have?

Tags: elf, stack, llvm

I was reading the Rust Unstable Book, and I saw a new feature for [`emit-stack-sizes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/compiler-flags/emit-stack-sizes.html#emit-stack-sizes),

> The rustc flag `-Z emit-stack-sizes` makes LLVM emit stack size metadata.

It goes on to say

> **NOTE: This LLVM feature only supports the ELF object format as of LLVM 8.0.** Using this flag with targets that use other object formats (e.g. macOS and Windows) will result in it being ignored.

The LLVM Feature it seems to be using is the `EmitStackSizeSection` option. What's the purpose of knowing the stack size? Does tooling use this? Is this an official feature of ELF and if so does the kernel make use of this? This seems to get recorded in the [ELF metadata under the sections `.stack_sizes`, `.rel.stack_sizes`, and `.rela.stack_sizes`](https://github.com/japaric/stack-sizes/blob/6de849728bd6092b86f73025decd03d53e323414/src/lib.rs#L149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This somewhat outlined here in [the original RFC, *"[eRFC] add `-Z emit-stack-sizes`"*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/51946)

> The end goal is to **enable whole program analysis of stack usage to prove absence of stack overflows at compile time.** Such property is important in systems that lack a MMU / MPU and where stack overflows can corrupt memory. And in systems that have protection against stack overflows such proof can be used to opt out of runtime checks (e.g. stack probes or the MPU).

And further in this [blog entry, *"Implementing a static stack usage analysis tool"*](https://blog.japaric.io/stack-analysis/). The tooling for this, with rust, is available here

- https://github.com/japaric/cargo-call-stack